# ValueError: Timeseries already present in CollectorRegistry

Tags: python, prometheus

Im trying to create a new Summary for one of my process but get this error -

```
ValueError: Timeseries already present in CollectorRegistry: tf_call_seconds
```

Not sure, why its been there. How can I delete the Timeseries object thats already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A metric can only be registered once, trying to register it again is a bug. Are you sure there's only one copy of this metric?

Usually this happens when you crate a metric in an instance or class, rather than at the file level.

Comment: I ran the code directly once and it failed..Immediately I ran the unittest for the same code then I get this error..Just because it failed first time, does it store the cache somewhere?